# FaceBook upload video using ONLY JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook, video, upload

How??
I try this code:

```
FB.api('/me/videos', 'post', {
   message: FacebookMessage,
   access_token: accessToken,
   source: "@HERE_WORKING_URL",
  // url: type[1],
   type: 'video',    
}, function(response){
    if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log('Error occured'+response.error.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
    comp(s++,photon.length);
});
```

and i get error: Error occured(#353) Missing video file

What wrong? How i can send video? Please help!

If i posting photo, its work!

Comment: Did u get this working? I'm having the same problem ...

Comment: Do you have the right permission set "publish_actions" on the Facebook App?